# Can a GetFilesAsync select only *.png images?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I have a `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileStack = await myFolder.GetFilesAsync();` but want to retrieve only *.png files. Is there a solution directly within the method ?

I guess I'll have to sort my `fileStack` and delete unwanted files otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery;
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(query, new[] {".png", ".jpg"});
queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Shallow;
var queryResult = myFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, I added .jpg since I used that in my own project and thought it would also be helpful to show how to include multiple extensions.